# Add value to XNA Vector2

Tags: xna

I wonder if it's possibel to add a value to X and Y in a Vector2? I have this code that creates a missile that use the position from the spaceship as a start position. But I would like to add some pixels so that the missile starts a little bit away from the spaceship. can I do that?

```
objectManager.AddNewMissileToList(new Missile(textureMissile, spaceship.spaceshipPosition, spaceship.spaceshipDirection));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like

```
Vector2 offset = new Vector2(2,1);
objectManager.AddNewMissileToList(new Missile(textureMissile, spaceship.spaceshipPosition + offset, spaceship.spaceshipDirection));
```

if the spaceShipDirection is directional vector

```
Vector2 offset = spaceship.spaceshipDirection * 1.5f;
objectManager.AddNewMissileToList(new Missile(textureMissile, spaceship.spaceshipPosition + offset, spaceship.spaceshipDirection));
```

or if the spaceShipDirection is float angle

```
Vector2 offset = new Vector2((float)Math.Sin(spaceship.spaceshipDirection),
                             (float)Math.Cos(spaceship.spaceshipDirection))
                 * 1.5f;

objectManager.AddNewMissileToList(new Missile(textureMissile, spaceship.spaceshipPosition + offset, spaceship.spaceshipDirection));
```

Comment: Thanks! I tested the first alternative, and it worked fine, until I rotated the ship! Is there a way to make it work also when the spaceship is rotating?

Comment: What is spaceshipDirection? Is it an angle?

Comment: That a good question! How can I see that? It could be radians!?

Comment: It's not working! There are red lines below the code and the error message is about invalid arguments!?

Comment: I'm writing it off the top of my head. I don't even know if spaceship.spaceshipDirection is float or Vector2 :)  Just get the idea that you can add vectors together and you can compute directional vector from angle, thats all you need to do what you want...

Comment: spaceship.spaceshipDirection is a Vector2

Comment: Then the second code should work, if it only shoots in different direction then spaceship is rotated, but when you rotate ship, missle direction rotates too, then just add or substract some value to make it work (or rotate your ship image)

Comment: It's almost perfect. But at some part of the rotation the position change and the missile start some pixels to the left of the spaceship

Comment: well thats because position of your ship is top left of the ship image, so either draw image in the center of the position, or add half of image size to rocket start offset